# How to set _NET_WM_STRUT for my app in python

Tags: x11, python, window-manager

I want to make a standalone status bar (something like polybar) in python. I chose tkinter to work on it but sadly I can't find any option to set `_NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL` and `_NET_WM_STRUT` which are obviously required to request needed space from the window manager. I'd appreciate any help on this matter as well as a suggestion of a different library that would perhaps perform better with my problem. Thanks in advance.